# Question should be closed as unclear

Tags: support, specific-question, vote-to-close

I was looking at my declined flags, and found a declined *Unclear what you're asking* for [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/126130/why-is-alignment-off-in-cells).

Since March the OP has not given any new information that is required to properly answer this. One answerer wasted time on a wild suggestion of what *might* be off, and asked for more info (link to sheet).

I cannot reraise my VTC, so I'm bringing the question to attention via this way. Can it be closed as unclear?

Comment: While it's good to be patient specially with those that ask their first question on this site, after a couple of days (or weeks if you prefer so) If the question is not clear down-vote it.

Comment: The actual "declining" of the flag likely came from a "Leave Open" vote in the close votes queue, so it wasn't intentionally dismissed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has now been closed.

As I mentioned in my comment, this was not due to any misjudgement on your part; the flag was not explicitly moderator declined, but autodeclined when "Leave Open" was selected in the CV queue.